# Deadlock in Java with ReentrantLock and Lock

Tags: java, deadlock

This snippet shows an example of a deadlock in Java by forcing **Thread1** to acquire **lock1** on **resource1** and **Thread2** to acquire **lock2** on **resource2**. Then Thread1 tries to acquire **lock2** and **Thread2** tries to acquire **lock1**.This causes a deadlock.

I was expecting to see Thread2 and Thread1 state to be **BLOCKED** according to [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java/lang/Thread.State.html#BLOCKED), instead, they are in **WAITING** state indefinitely when I monitor the status with `thread.getState()`.

Can you help me understand why?

Consider that the locks are declared in the main class as:

```
    Lock lock1 = new ReentrantLock();
    Lock lock2 = new ReentrantLock();
```

This is the code of the `ThreadClass`

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;

public class ThreadClass extends Thread {
    private Lock lock1; 
    private Lock lock2;
    private Resource resource1; 
    private Resource resource2;

    public ThreadClass(Resource resource1, Resource resource2, String name, Lock lock1, Lock lock2) {
        this.resource1 = resource1;
        this.resource2 = resource2;
        this.lock1 = lock1;
        this.lock2 = lock2;
        this.setName(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("Thread1")) {
            lock1.lock();
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": Using " + resource1.name);
            // Simulating work on RESOURCE 1
               
            lock2.lock();
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": Using " + resource2.name);
            // Simulating work on RESOURCE 2
            lock2.unlock();

            lock1.unlock();
        }
        if (Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("Thread2")) {
            lock2.lock();


            // Simulating work on RESOURCE 2

            lock1.lock();
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": Using resource1");
            lock1.unlock();

            lock2.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you refer to is about the intrinsic locks - the ones built into every Java object (also called monitors). They are a low level, slightly legacy mechanism with known caveats. The intrinsic locks are used with the `synchronized` keyword and are only taken when a thread enters a block of code statically marked as `synchronized`.

You are using a different, higher level API, so whatever the documentation says about locks - does not apply. I have never looked inside the implementation of the `ReentrantLock`, but - as you can see from the `Thread`s status - it's not using the `synchronized` block to park the thread, but rather a call to the `Object`'s `wait` method (which is always made from inside a `synchronized` block and forms the other low-level primitive upon which Java's threading is built).

Comment: I see. Then I have another question. When a thread is in WAITING state, why does a deadlock occur? Shouldn't the thread release the resource it acquired when it enters the WAITING state? This happens when we use wait() in a synchronized block.

Comment: @gaetano `Object::wait` corresponds to `Condition::await` in the locks API. Your code is not using `await`. The threads in your example are blocked on the call to `lock()`, which corresponds to trying to _enter_ a `synchronized` block. Also, an already-acquired lock is not automatically released when you try to acquire a different lock (whether you're using synchronized or the locks API).

Comment: @gaetano There are no "resources" assigned statically to locks (you could change your code to just print "using resource 1" and "using resource 2"). The only "resource" is the lock itself. And there are two separate mechanisms - the concurrent API and the intrinsic locks (with the synchronized-wait mechanics) - you cannot use your knowledge of the first to reason about the latter, they are different. A `Lock` can be implemented using the synchronized-wait primitive, but it doesn't have to.